# Node create progrmatically with multiselect

Tags: 7

I am creating a node progrmatically.

here is my code..

```
     $node = new stdClass();
      $node->type=$type;
      $node->status = 1;
      $node->uid = $uid;

        foreach($_POST as $field_name=>$field_value) {
          $node->$field_name=array('und'=>array(0=>array('value'=>$field_value)));

        }
node_save($node);
```

this is working fine. if we have a single value for each field.. Now i have a filed having select box with multiple select. How to save them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep adding new values underneath the language array, for example:

```
foreach ($_POST as $field_name => $field_value) {
  $node->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = $field_value;
}
```

Comment: [type] => test
    [status] => 1
    [uid] => 
    [field_name] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => helo
                        )

                )

        )

Comment: i was expecting my post field name

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you clarify? Does the above not work? If not could you edit the new code you're using into the question?

Comment: i am using advance rest console for posting parameter.. i need fields name what i posted

Comment: Ah ok, so just make that change and you'll be good to go

Comment: still not working.. it is printing 
[field_test] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 1
                                    [1] => 2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

but it must be print something like this

Comment: [field_test] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

Comment: Sorry but those array printouts mean nothing to me; you might need to adjust the code to fit your exact use case, but that's the correct method for adding multiple values to a field, I use it practically every day. Check that the data you're receiving in `$_POST` is formatted correctly for the way you're using it, that's all I can really advise. Also check your PHP logic. If these are supposed to be multiple values for a single field, why are you changing the field name every time?

Comment: sorry above code is not working for me

Comment: I can only advise you to check your PHP logic and the `$_POST` variable. The code in the answer is the correct way to use the Drupal API, if your PHP logic is incorrect then that won't help you. You need to fix the basic PHP problem first

Comment: this is my post array

    Array
(
    [field_test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [title] => helo
)

Comment: Sorry, you're now into the realms of asking a basic PHP question which we can't answer here. You just need to decide how best to loop over your data to extract the correct values, and apply it to the code I've given in the answer. I would suggest your post array is not formatted in a way that's conducive to being looped over, and you either need to extract the data first, or re-build the API resource so it gives you what you're looking for